# Java inputMismatchException in calculator

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator

i'm making a calculator but i'm having trouble using the scanner input, i declared the variables as double but if i use i get this error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at ProgramTUI.main(ProgramTUI.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ProgramTUI {

    public static double add(double a, double b) {

      return a+b;
    }

    public static double substract(double a, double b) {

      return a-b;
    }    

    public static double multiply(double a, double b) {

      return a*b;
    }

    public static double divide(double a, double b) {

      return a/b;
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int choice;
        double a, b;

        System.out.println("1- Add");
        System.out.println("2- Sub");
        System.out.println("3- Mul");
        System.out.println("4- Div");
        System.out.print("Elige la operacion -");
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);

        choice = var.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce el primer numero -");
        a = var.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Introduce el segundo numero -");
        b = var.nextDouble();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print(add(a,b));
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print(substract(a,b));
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print(multiply(a,b));
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.print(divide(a,b));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

With int numbers the program work just fine, i declared a and b with var.nextDouble(); so i don't know what's going on.

Comment: What do your `double`s look like when you enter them in your program?

Comment: did you tried debugging?

Comment: I enter them like this: 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using wrong decimal separator, try something like this:

```
Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: This solved it!  What's the decimal separator that i should us without the Locale?

Comment: try comma - like 1,5

Answer (score 0):

You program will fail if whatever you input can not be interpreted as int for `var.nextInt();` and double for `var.nextDouble();`

This might be due to the system locale having another number format.

You can use this to force the English format:

```
Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Or you can get the Numbers as strings and parse them

```
      try 
      {  
         value = Integer.parseInt(value);  
      } 
      catch (NumberFormatException e) 
      {  
         conversionfailed = true;  
      }
```